# SherlockActionBar is not working on Android 2.3.6 (Force Close)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

However, on Android 4.0.3 it is working fine. 
Isn't Sherlock supposed to give `ActionBar` for 2.xx versions too ?

I added : `android:theme="@style/Sherlock.__Theme.Light"` to the manifest file.

I am not running anything on the application only this:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

I tried also `extends SherlockFragmentActivity`
It also force closed on `2.3.6`. However, on `4.0.3` it worked.
Any expert can tell me where the problem is?

EDIT:

```
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.lau.autointernetconnector/edu.lau.autointernetconnector.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:1003)
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:915)
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:849)
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SherlockActivity.java:229)
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    at edu.lau.autointernetconnector.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
04-01 23:24:29.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18249):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: An exception would help...

Comment: @LukasKnuth I added them :)

Comment: It was just explained in the exception `You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.`

Comment: haha yes i just noticed... I hope someone will benefit from this question. Thank you guys:)

Answer (score 1):

Although you answered your question yourself (based of the comment ChristopheCVB gave) I'd still like to add something.

> However, on Android 4.0.3 it is working fine. Isn't Sherlock supposed
>   to give ActionBar for 2.xx versions too ?

ActionBarSherlock only provides the ActionBar for versions below Honeycomb. The ActionBar you see on HC+ are all native implementations.

`@style/Sherlock.__Theme.Light` will not fail on HC+ because they already have all necessary styles set.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue... I can't believe i couldn't solve it until I posted it here.

I put this in manifest : `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light"` instead of `android:theme="@style/Sherlock.__Theme.Light"` and it worked :)